# Angular 15 with Jest Preset Angular reports: Component ... is not resolved... Did you run and wait for 'resolveComponentResources()'?

Tags: angular, jestjs

Jest used to work with angular for me (on ng11, 7 months ago). Then I accidentally rebuilt my package-lock and some updated dependency somewhere broke things so I tabled it.

The other day, I updated to ng15, and tests are running but are all failing with `Did you run and wait for 'resolveComponentResources()'?` edit: not all tests are failing with that error; just those that rely on `TestBed.createComponent` or `TestBed.inject`

I've seen a lot of bug reports mentioning this kind of problem, stretching back to ng8, so I assume it's just some kind of incompatibility or bad conf. The most recent I found reported success by downgrading typescript to 4.7 but that's not possible with ng15.

The project is node+angular together in separate folders (the root package.json controls the server and the jest runner). Relevant snippets below:

package.json

```
{
  ...
  "engineStrict": true,
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.12.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "./test-data/test-data.sh && jest --detectOpenHandles",
    "test:watch": "./test-data/test-data.sh && jest --detectOpenHandles --watch"
  },
  "jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.{js,ts}",
      "!**/*.spec.{js,ts}",
      "!**/serviceWorker.js",
      "!**/node_modules/**",
      "!**/data/**",
      "!**/environments/**",
      "!**/migrations/**",
      "!**/server/config/**",
      "!**/vendors/**",
      "!**/coverage/**",
      "!**/models/**",
      "!**/test-data/**",
      "!**/migration.js",
      "!**/app.module.ts",
      "!**/*webpack.config.js",
      "!**/*main.ts",
      "!**/*polyfills.ts"
    ],
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/*/node_modules/",
      "<rootDir>/client/dist/"
    ],
    "projects": [
      {
        "displayName": "backend",
        "testEnvironment": "node",
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/server/**/*.spec.js"
        ],
        "modulePaths": [
          "<rootDir>/server/"
        ]
      },
      {
        "displayName": "frontend",
        "testEnvironment": "jsdom",
        "preset": "<rootDir>/client/node_modules/jest-preset-angular",
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
          "<rootDir>/client/setupJest.ts"
        ],
        "testMatch": [
          "<rootDir>/client/src/**/*.spec.ts"
        ],
        "modulePaths": [
          "<rootDir>/client/"
        ],
        "snapshotSerializers": [
          "<rootDir>/client/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment"
        ],
        "transform": {
          "^.+\\.(ts|js|mjs|html|svg)$": "<rootDir>/client/node_modules/jest-preset-angular"
        },
        "transformIgnorePatterns": ["node_modules/(?!.*\\.mjs$)"],
        "globals": {
          "ts-jest": {
            "tsconfig": "<rootDir>/client/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "stringifyContentPathRegex": "\\.html$"
          }
        },
        "globalSetup": "<rootDir>/client/node_modules/jest-preset-angular/global-setup"
      }
    ]
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "ajv-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "db-migrate-mysql": "^1.1.10",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "29.3.1",
    "mysql-migrations": "^1.0.6",
    "node-env-run": "^4.0.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.19.4",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "pino-colada": "^1.6.0",
    "ts-json-schema-generator": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

client/package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.5.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.4",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.4",
    ...
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "0.1500.4",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.1.0",
    "@types/clone": "^2.1.1",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.7",
    "@types/string-similarity": "^4.0.0",
    ...
    "jest-preset-angular": "^12.2.3",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "rxjs-watcher": "^1.1.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0"
  }
}
```

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "rosterizer": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "sass"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/rosterizer",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/site.webmanifest",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/css/main.sass"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/marked/marked.min.js"
            ],
            "webWorkerTsConfig": "tsconfig.worker.json",
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "custom-webpack.config.ts",
              "replaceDuplicatePlugins": true
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            },
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "3mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myApp:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "myApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "myApp:build"
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "myApp:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "development": {
              "devServerTarget": "myApp:serve:development"
            },
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "myApp:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

custom-webpack.config.ts

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
};
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2020",
      "dom",
      "ESNext.String"
    ],
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "emitDecoratorMetadata":true
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin()
    ]
};
```

Comment: Post. Your. Code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @E.Maggini Like, what part of my code?

Comment: Other than the fact that you should remove `^` and `~` and commit to regularly update your libraries with `npm-check-updates` in order to avoid the package-lock.json corruption you mention, there is nothing here specific to your failed tests. Post an actual tests file that is failing and the related TS file being tested.

Comment: Did you manage to find the cause and resolved the issue? We're using Angular15, and are only just starting to build Jest UnitTests for our front-end. The UnitTests which test simple Typescript stuff (e.g. regexes) are currently working fine, but for the Component test I'm getting that same `Did you run and wait for 'resolveComponentResources()'?` error for the `TestBed.createComponent`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen the solution was to abandon Jest in favor of Jasmine. It pains me, as I really like Jest but the instability and potential for big breakages in the future scared me away.

Comment: @jugglervr Ah ok. I can understand. I've actually been able to resolve the error on my end by updating jest; jest-angular-preset; _and_ typescript all three to the current latest stable versions ([details on which versions those are I've posted here](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/1617#issuecomment-1412096144)). But it's without a doubt instable, and I'm not convinced I won't see the same error again in the future when we update one or multiple of these three dependencies.. :/ (PS: Apparently the error started occurring because of a change in TypeScript 4.8+.)